# how to explain 8.2-8 = 0.19999999999 in C#

Tags: c#

code:

```
Console.WriteLine(8.3-8);
Console.WriteLine(8.2-8);
Console.WriteLine(7.2-7);
```

the code above will output:

```
0.300000000000001
0.199999999999999
0.2
```

Comment: [Representation of floating point numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx). Try `8.3m-8` instead

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890477/c-sharp-wrong-subtraction-12-345-12-0-345000000000001) is rather a duplicate and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net/618596#618596) you find a good explanation.

Answer (score 5):

that's the double rounding issue. SO is full of it. Try to work with Decimal

```
Console.WriteLine((decimal)8.3 - 8);
Console.WriteLine((decimal)8.2 - 8);
Console.WriteLine((decimal)7.2 - 7);
```

Comment: SO should implement an AI to auto answer such IndexoutOfRange, Nullreference and Double rounding stuff :D

Comment: Instead of `(decimal)8.3` you can use `8.3m` for shorter notation.